# If $A$ is a simple finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra then $A\cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove the problem 17 of chapter 13 of the book *Algebra: a Graduate Course* (by Martin Isaacs), which is:

> Let $A$ be a simple finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. Show that $A\cong M_n(\mathbb{C})$ for
> some integer $n\geq 1$.

In one direction I'm trying to use the fact that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is generated by the $E_{ij}$ to construct the bijection with the generators of $A$ but I don't know if it is a good option.

Comment: Are you sure it is true? What about $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: This is not true. There is a theorem by Wedderburn which says that every finite dimensional $simple$ algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. It has to be simple, this is necessary.

Comment: What Mark said. You may have left out an assumption. Isaacs knows this for sure.

Comment: @Mark is probably right. I don't have access to that book, but google books says the title of chapter 13 is **Simple Modules and Primitive Rings**.

Comment: Do you mean $A$ can be embedded in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Sorry, the problem don't say anything about if A is simple or not, but reading the book I believe too that A have to be simple.

Comment: What edition? I just saw that the 2009 edition included the word "simple" in this exercise.

Comment: @cristianR Note that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ itself is a simple algebra, so a non simple algebra can't be isomorphic to it. So if the exercise didn't include the word "simple" then this is a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The field $\mathbb{C}$ is not important. The statement is true for any algebraically closed field $F$.

Take a simple right $A$-module $V$. This is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, because it is a quotient of $A$ modulo some maximal right ideal. Therefore its endomorphism ring is a finite dimensional division algebra over $F$. Since $F$ is algebraically closed the dimension must be $1$, so the endomorphism ring is $F$.

Also, the annihilator of $V$ in $A$ must be $\{0\}$, because $A$ is simple, so $V$ is faithful. Thus Wedderburn-Artin allows us to conclude that $A$ is isomorphic to $M_n(F)$, where $n=\dim_FV$ and the isomorphism is easily checked to be an $F$-algebra isomorphism.